# PayPal Express has been updated to PayPal Checkout: Is there a way to add this to Expresso Store 2?

Tags: expresso-store, paypal-express-checkout

PayPal Checkout has features not available in PayPal Express.  Is there a way to add it to Expresso Store 2 through Omnipay?

[PayPal Checkout Overview](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/)